# Why does & (intersection) operator remove the non-intersected property?

Tags: typescript

I have the following logic:

```
interface ResultBase {
    readonly success: boolean
}

type Result<Payload = undefined> = ResultBase & (Payload extends undefined ? {
    readonly payload?: unknown
} : {
    readonly payload: Payload
})

function getResult<Payload = undefined>(payload: Payload): Result<Payload> {
    return {
//  ^^^^^^
        success: true,
        payload,
    }
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/mb1OoN).*

The marked `return` statement is underscored with a compiler error:

```
Type '{ success: true; payload: Payload; }' is not assignable to type 'Result<Payload>'.
  Type '{ success: true; payload: Payload; }' is not assignable to type 'Payload extends undefined ? { readonly payload?: unknown; } : { readonly payload: Payload; }'.
```

I wonder, why doesn't the conditional type in the error message include the `success` property? Shouldn't it be included by `ResultBase & …`?

Comment: First things first, did you really intend to use string literal types? Even if `Bar` _is_ `string`, not all strings are `'string'`. Also what makes you say it's removing the non-intersected property - if you comment out `foo: 'whatever'` you can see it complains that `foo` is missing.

Comment: The error is not to do with the `foo` property and the intersection, it happens even if you simplify to just the `bar` property: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMA8AhAhgJwHxQC8UAFNjlBAB7ARIAmAzlI8DsilAPxQDeAUFCFQcELPQD2SADYgoAI1wAuKAHJW7VKv4BfKCoHCRYyTLmKcK1QFckAayQSA7km06AlP34AzWwGNgBCkoFAhgeA5MXDwSCxVydxUI1Cj8PkFhUWBrHCR0oyMLABoMoR1dIA

Comment: If you're claiming that `A` is assignable to `B & C`, then it needs to be assignable to each of `B` and `C`.  If it is assignable to `B` but not to `C`, then you can expect an error talking about `C` (the problem) and not `B` (not the problem).  (e.g., if you ask for a red apple and I give you a red pear, you would say "this isn't an apple", not necessarily "this isn't a red apple") Does that explain it well enough? If so I could write up an answer fleshing that out. If not, what is missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that's a good explanation, thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've added some semantics to the code

Comment: @IMSoP I appreciate the clarification! I think, I have to stick to using intersection though, because changing it would be like asking a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm not going to talk much about the underlying issue with the compiler failing to accept your implementation.  Trying to assign values to a type involving a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is almost always going to fail, because the compiler doesn't have the higher-order reasoning ability necessary to understand what they mean.  This is out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't digress further.

---

Generally speaking, if you try to assign a type `T` to an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `X & Y`, it can only type check if `T` is seen to be assignable to both `X` and `Y`.  If the compiler doesn't think that `T` is assignable to at least one of those, then it will report an error about the broken one.  So if `T` is assignable to `X` but not `Y`, then you can expect an error message like `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Y'`.  There's no need to mention `X` because it's not the problem.

By analogy: if you ask for a red apple and I give you a red pear instead, you would probably object with "but this isn't an apple", without feeling the need to mention "red" in your sentence.  There's nothing *incorrect* with saying "but this isn't a red apple", but the word "red" isn't really the source of the issue.

In your example above, `T` is `{ success: true; payload: Payload; }`, `X` is equivalent to `{ readonly success: boolean }`, and `Y` is equivalent to `Payload extends undefined ? { readonly payload?: unknown; } : { readonly payload: Payload; }`.  The compiler is happy enough to see that `T` is assignable to `X`. But it is unable to verify that `T` is assignable to `Y`.  And so the error message does not say anything about `ResultBase &`, because it's not directly relevant to the error.